# ack: how to match beginning of words?

Tags: ack

I'm using ack like this:  `ack-grep assets\\.`    (on Ubuntu)

However, I want to **exclude** results which do not begin with "assets".  For example: siteassets.

So far I've tried `ack-grep ^assets\\.` and other random stuff.

(in Vim regex, the pattern is like this: `\<assets\.`  e.g.  :help \<)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ack` command has an option `-w` to force PATTERN match whole word.00

> -w, --word-regexp             Force PATTERN to match only whole words

So, you can use

```
ack -w assets\.
```

According to [doc](https://beyondgrep.com/documentation/)

Answer (score 5):

\< in `vim` is a regex "word boundary." The equivalent of that in Perl's regex, which `ack` uses, is \b. So, in your case:

`$ ack '\bassets'`